# Looping within the results of a Pig Group By

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Let's say I have a game with player ids.  Each id can have multiple character names (playerNames) and we have a score for each of those names.  I would like to total all the scores per playerName, and calculate the percentage score per player name per id.

So, for instance:

```
id  playerName  playerScore
01  Test        45
01  Test2       15
02  Joe         100
```

would output

```
id  {(playerName, playerScore, percentScore)}
01  {(Test, 45, .75), (Test2, 15, .25)}
02  {(Joe, 100, 1.0)}
```

Here's how I did it:

```
data = LOAD 'someData.data' AS (id:int, playerName:chararray, playerScore:int);
grouped = GROUP data BY id;

withSummedScore = FOREACH grouped GENERATE SUM(data.playerScore) AS summedPlayerScore, FLATTEN(data);

withPercentScore = FOREACH withSummedScore GENERATE data::id AS id, data::playerName AS playerName, (playerScore/summedPlayerScore) AS percentScore;

percentScoreIdroup = GROUP withPercentScore By id;
```

Currently, I do this with 2 GROUP BY statements, and I was curious if they were both necessary, or if there's a more efficient way to do this.  Can I reduce this to a single GROUP BY?   Or, is there a way I can iterate over the bag of tuples and add percentScore to all of them without flattening the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not do this without 2 `GROUP`, and the reason is more fundamental than just Pig:

1. To get the total number of points you need a linear pass through the player's scores.
2. Then, you need another linear pass over the player's scores to calculate the fraction. You can **not** do this before you know the sum.

Having said that, if the player's number of `playerName`s is small, I'd write a UDF that takes a bag of player scores and outputs a bag of score-per-playerName tuples, since each `GROUP` will generate a reducer and the process becomes ridiculously slow. A UDF that takes the bag would have to do those 2 linear passes as well, but if the bags are small enough, it won't matter and it'll certainly be an order of magnitude faster than creating another reducer.